# zeromq library cross compile configure err, unsupported system :elf

Tags: linux, mips, cross-compiling, zeromq, toolchain

I am trying to cross compile Zeromq library on MIPS platform.
I have tried version 2.2, 3.2.4, 4.0.4, but all of them fail to pass the configure checking

The environment variables, CC, CPP, CXX, LD, AR, RANLIB are set.
Then I run  ./configure --host=mips

Linux kernel: 2.6.31
gcc version: 4.3.3

```
checking dynamic linker characteristics... no
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are using Intel C compiler... no
checking whether we are using Sun Studio C compiler... no
checking whether we are using clang C compiler... no
checking whether we are using gcc >= 4 C compiler... yes
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking whether we are using Intel C++ compiler... no
checking whether we are using Sun Studio C++ compiler... no
checking whether we are using clang C++ compiler... no
checking whether we are using gcc >= 4 C++ compiler... yes
checking whether to enable debugging information... no
checking whether to enable code coverage... no
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for clock_gettime in -lrt... yes
configure: error: unsupported system: elf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, disable the epoll if you get err

> Function not implemented (epoll.cpp:41)
>
> Aborted

before configure

> export CXXFLAGS=-DZMQ_FORCE_POLL

Start to cross compile

Use

> ./configure --host=mips-linux

There may be an error when you type make

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/justinyu/Development/project/askey_cc/zeromq-3.2.4'                                                                       
justinyu@justinyu-ubuntu:~/Development/project/askey_cc/zeromq-3.2.4$ make
Making all in src 
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/justinyu/Development/project/askey_cc/zeromq-3.2.4/src'
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/justinyu/Development/project/askey_cc/zeromq-3.2.4/src'
  CXX    libzmq_la-address.lo
  CXX    libzmq_la-clock.lo
  CXX    libzmq_la-ctx.lo
In file included from ctx.hpp:31,
                 from ctx.cpp:32:
array.hpp:142:41: error: macro "index" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
In file included from ctx.hpp:31,
                 from ctx.cpp:32:
array.hpp:142: error: function definition does not declare parameters
make[2]: *** [libzmq_la-ctx.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/justinyu/Development/project/askey_cc/zeromq-3.2.4/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/justinyu/Development/project/askey_cc/zeromq-3.2.4/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Fix it by adding some line in array.hpp

```
#ifdef index
#undef index
#endif

#ifndef __ZMQ_ARRAY_INCLUDED__
#define __ZMQ_ARRAY_INCLUDED__

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

namespace zmq 
{
```